# hql/jpql hibernate with jpa not working for cos and radions function

Tags: jpql, trigonometry

following query works fine in mysql query browser but when I move this to either jpql or native query and tried to execute using entity manager not getting any results also not seeing any errors too.

I am using Hibernate core 3.3.0 Entity Manager 3.4.0 with spring IOC for entityManager for injection

```
select * from location
where 1=1
    and latitude is not null and longitude is not null
    and (6371 *

    acos(   cos( radians(12.922253 ) ) *
            cos( radians(latitude) ) *
            cos( radians( 77.614417 ) - radians(longitude) )
            + sin( radians(12.922253 ) ) *
            sin( radians( latitude ) )
        ) ) < 100.0
```

Comment: its actually "and" only and not && corrected the description

Answer (score 0):

I believe "&&" is not part of JPQL.  Try replacing it with "and".